# How can I get the mount point of my USB drive without using awk?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script that uses awk to find a usb and then parse the files from it. It finds it with the following command which I find really messy.

```
THUMBDRIVE=$(df | tail - 1 | awk '{print $6}')
```

My question is if there is another way to do this function without using the obfuscated language of awk. I get I can look up the USB with commands like these below. However, I can't get these to behave the way I really want them to like above. I believe there has to be an easier way of doing this anyone have a clear way of performing this?

```
 ls /dev/sda* 
 df -h
 lsblk
```

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call awk "obfuscated" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU `df`, you can use its `--output` option:

```
thumbdrive=$(df --output=target | tail -n 1)
```

This prints only the target column.

Your command likely was supposed to say `tail -1`, by the way; `tail - 1` would read from standard input and then try to open a file named `1`. The `-1` syntax is still supported for compatibility reasons, but `-n 1` instead is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

awk is far from being obfuscated, rather use it to replace the `tail` and print the `$6` of the last record:

```
$ thumbdrive=$(df | awk 'END{print $6}')
```

My output for `echo $thumbdrive` is: `/mnt`

Whether or not `$0` (and `$6`) is preserved in `END` [is debatable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356444/is-the-awk-end-behavior-to-keep-the-last-line-loaded-in-0-in-the-man-page) but worked on GNU awk, mawk, original-awk and Busybox awk. If you want to be on the safe side, store the `$6` to a variable and use it on the next round:

```
$ thumbdrive=$(df | awk '{var=$6}END{print var}')
```

`strace`'ing `df`revealed:

```
...
open("/proc/self/mountinfo", O_RDONLY)  = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "16 21 0:16 / /sys rw,nosuid,node"..., 1024) = 1024
...
```

so if you're on Linux, you could drop the `df` as well:

```
$ awk 'END{print $5}' /proc/self/mountinfo 
/mnt
```

See `man proc` for more info on that.